# Strange rows when booting Arch installer

Tags: arch-linux, system-installation, graphics

When I boot from the Arch installer USB drive, I get the text printed in some strange rows pattern. I believe it's related to graphics driver issues (I have an Nvidia GTX 1080). How can I fix this to see a normal prompt?

[image: Picture of problem]

Comment: The problem did not go away on its own; it's reproducible. It was solved by unplugging secondary monitors and booting with only a single monitor attached. I don't understand how this is unhelpful to future readers?

Comment: For one that's not a solution but a workaround. And the workaround clearly shows that it's a defect/bug of `nouveau` in the *current* kernel. Your observation should go to upstream as a bug report for `nouveau`.

Comment: While that’s all true, it’s still helpful to future readers encountering this problem while installing Arch, before they get the Nvidia driver set up.

Comment: Only for specific card with specific configuration (type/number of monitors). That's why they put  "cannot reproduced" as the reason for off-topic. Also it's pretty much a general sense/approach to just blacklist it (as I mentioned in my other comment) when it hiccups in *any* way. Not much point to tell "oh with *that version* of ISO/kernel and *that* card you may want to *try* leave only one monitor connected *assuming* you have more" to new comers. Especially not on an SE site.

Answer (score 1):

It was solved by unplugging my extra monitors. Booting with only one monitor attached solves the problem.

Comment: It is likely a driver problem, I think archlinux may start with some VESA thing, which should work, but it doesn't.

Comment: @peterh Linux kernel comes with the RE driver `nouveau` for nvidia cards. Most distros makes use of that out of the box and provide means to install the proprietary/official nvidia driver, so does Arch.

Comment: `nouveau` isn't supposed to work well for all cards, especially new ones. In case it doesn't, you can boot with `nomodeset` or the more specfic `modprobe.blacklist=nouveau` for the time being, and have the official driver installed for the new installation (i.e. include `nvidia` when `pacstrap`)

Comment: @TomYan And it does even in the case if it is booted from a pendrive? What if the driver is buggy? What if the driver isn't buggy, but it doesn't support the actual device version? I think, in these cases, the VESA driver start to work.

Comment: @peterh As I said, the `nouveau` driver is in-kernel. So whether it's live/installer/pendrive doesn't matter. There's no such thing as VESA driver when it comes to the kernel part. It either loads a kernel modesetting driver and do KMS or not. There's a VESA DDX/driver when it comes to the X part, but it's rarely used these days (probably not very usable anyway). The only case it might comes in handy is when the KMS driver does not work well and you blacklisted it (without loading any UMS proprietary driver),  but you still want to start X.